# The extension manifest is invalid, CompositeC1WebFormExtensions.vsix

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c1-cms

I just downloaded the CompositeC1WebFormExtensions.vsix from the official composite CMS C1 documentation website and I'm getting an error when trying to install this.

I'm on Windows 8 using Visual Studio 2010 pro

CompositeC1WebFormExtensions.vsix

Has anyone been able to successfully install this extension?

Thanks

David

Comment: Works for sure on VS2012, most likely not supported by VS2010. Will try to get a more definite answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that VSIX extensions

- CompositeC1WebFormExtensions.vsix
- CompositeC1RazorExtensions.vsix

are only compatible with **Visual Studio 2012**, as it reads on these pages:

1. http://docs.composite.net/Functions/User-Control-Functions/Creating-User-Control-Functions/Creating-User-Control-Functions-in-Visual-Studio
2. http://docs.composite.net/Functions/Razor/Creating-Razor-Functions/Creating-Razor-Functions-in-Visual-Studio

> **Note**. The current version of the extension works with Visual Studio
>   2012 only.

Answer (score 1):

David i am also using Windows 8 .I have installed visual studio 2010 and 2012. i got this CompositeC1WebFormExtensions.vsix  working well with Visual studio 2012...

I think it is compatible with visual studio 2012 only...

Vishnu Nadesh